# Revealing pattern usecase

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, factory, revealing-module-pattern

I'm reading a book called "Learning javascript design patterns" by Addy Osmani. This book is great.

There's an example of using the revealing design pattern:

```
var myRevealingModule = (function () {

    var privateVar = "Ben Cherry",
        publicVar = "Hey there!";

    function privateFunction() {
        console.log( "Name:" + privateVar );
    }

    function publicSetName( strName ) {
        privateVar = strName;
    }

    function publicGetName() {
        privateFunction();
    }


    // Reveal public pointers to
    // private functions and properties

    return {
        setName: publicSetName,
        greeting: publicVar,
        getName: publicGetName
    };

})();

myRevealingModule.setName( "Paul Kinlan" );
```

Now, of course I understand how it works, but my question simpler- what is the use case for using this in a regular, classic node webapp?

let's say I have a car module, that I wish to create in some procedure I have. I can't see how can I use the pattern in this case. How can I pass arguments to make `new Car(args)`?

Should I use this pattern for singletons? to create factories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This pattern is used to encapsulate some private state while exposing ("revealing") a public interface.

There can be many use cases for this pattern but in it's core it shows how to separate the implementation (the private variables) from the API (the exposed functions) which is not trivial to achieve in javascript.

It's a good idea to use this whenever you have a module which has a state.

To provide arguments, just expose an API function that accepts arguments, e.g.

```
return {
    createCar: function(model, mileage) { ... }
}
```

Comment: well, this is an example for the factory pattern. it's a fair usage and I'm aware of it. the question is what other use cases I have for using the revealing module.

Comment: I think this name is misleading as this actually applies to functions as well as modules, if instead of an object literal you returned a function you have now a function that can have internal state between invocations (that's another usecase)

Comment: function that has different state between invocations. Sounds horrible- I have to admit. function should be a function and that's it, IMO. The weird thing is to treat the function as a stateful object, and not just as callback for async actions. I guess that using this pattern for factory is the best use case.

Comment: @Chen there are perfectly valid use cases such as [memoized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) functions

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is a bit of a strange language, sometimes doing strange things if you don’t follow best practices and if you’re not familiar with the ECMA standard. There are numerous strange things in the JavaScript syntax, one of those being the self-executing (self-invoking) functions...

more details you can read here

```
 http://blog.mgechev.com/2012/08/29/self-invoking-functions-in-javascript-or-immediately-invoked-function-expression/
```

You can pass arguments like this :

```
https://jsfiddle.net/6bhn80oz/
```

Answer (score 0):

I often use it in angular 1 when I create services. For me, it is easier to know which methods and/or variables I can access in the service, and keep everything else outside of the `return {}` private.

```
angular.module('myModule')
.factory('someService', function () {
    function myFunction(){
    }
    return{
        getSomething:myFunction
    }
});
```